# Reference book on metric spaces.

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, book-recommendation

As the title says, I would like a good book on metric spaces. My knowledge is very basic on real analysis. I searched this site, and came up with *Set Theory and Metric Spaces* by Kaplanski, but I don't know if it's good for first reading. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: i think this is good here https://books.google.de/books/about/Metric_Spaces.html?id=aP37I4QWFRcC&redir_esc=y

Comment: Wade's "introduction to analysis" starts very basic, but the metric space section is helpful. i liked it when i started learning the subject.

Comment: I second Sonnhard's recommendation of Searcoid; I own the book and have found it useful. Depending on your level, you might also take a look at Victor Bryant's elegant little book *Metric Spaces: Iteration and Applications*. It is less comprehensive and starts at a more elementary level but gives excellent expositions of important ideas (contraction mapping, etc.).

Comment: I second Victor Bryant's book. I have taught undergraduate courses out of it, and it works quite well for that purpose.